# Alternate approach to run MTM (Automated) test case - with result populating in MTM

Tags: automation, mstest, microsoft-test-manager

Requirement - Run automated regression suite present in MTM on remote machines but not having to do that manually from MTM. Also, making sure that result is getting updated in MTM against that test case.

What I am doing now is select test cases -> Right click -> run with options -> select "build in use" and Environment(Where i have 6 different remote machines)

I am looking for an alternative way to trigger the test cases when i get the new build. Again, run the failed test case for 2 more time before looking into what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The TFS Build Server can be wired up to do this. MTM did not do cron/scheduled jobs last time I checked.

Comment: I got some stuff on net - https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-running-automated-web-tests-mtm/   .I will try to implement this and see if this is going to help.